# Should this take so long to complete?

Tags: php

My page load goes from 650-700ms to 1.5-1.6s when I append the following code to my script:

```
$authpts = array();
foreach ($obj["pro"] as $key => $val) {
    $c_recs = count($recs);
    for ($i=0; $i<$c_recs; $i++) {
        if ($recs[$i][0] === $key) {
            $wr = $recs[$i][1];
            break;
        }
    }
    $c_val = count($val);
    for ($i=0; $i<$c_val; $i++) {
        if (!array_key_exists($val[$i]["authid"], $authpts))
            $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] = 0;
        $ratio = 0;
        if (strlen($c_wr) > 0) {
            $ratio = comparetime($val[$i]["time"], $wr);
            $ratio = $ratio[0];
        }
        $rbonus = ($ratio > 0) ? pow($ratio, (2 / $ratio)) : 0;
        $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] = $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] + ($c_val - $i) * (1 + $rbonus);
    }
}
```

Now, this might be acceptable if my script ended here, but there are three more similar loops that need to occur after this one. Currently if I enable everything, the page takes about 15 seconds to load which is completely unacceptable.

`$obj["pro"]` has about 1500 entries to iterate over and `$recs` has about 3000. I have tried optimizing it as best I could, but was wondering if there was a more efficient way to perform the same functionality.

Basically I need to find any occurrence of a string (the key from the outer array, `$obj["pro"]`) in the `$recs` array if it exists (there should only be one match if any; this is why I break when a match is found), then obtain a corresponding value contained in the matching index of `$recs`.

The next step is to create a new array key in a different initially empty array (`$authpts`) with an initial value of 0 (points), then, if a match was found, look through each of the outer array's key values and compare one of them (`time`) with the stored value from `$recs` to calculate a ratio bonus indicative of performance.

The final step is to add a number of points to `$authpts` calculated from the index and the ratio bonus if it applies.

As a note, when this code was in javascript it took much less time to complete.

=========================

**Edit**: here is the entire calcpoints function (I won't describe it as there's simply far too much information which is mostly self-explanatory):

```
function calcpoints($obj, $recs) {
    global $points, $wpnspeeds;
    $authpts = array();
    foreach ($obj["pro"] as $key => $val) {
        $c_recs = count($recs);
        for ($i=0; $i<$c_recs; $i++) {
            if ($recs[$i][0] === $key) {
                $wr = $recs[$i][1];
                break;
            }
        }
        $c_val = count($val);
        for ($i=0; $i<$c_val; $i++) {
            if (!array_key_exists($val[$i]["authid"], $authpts))
                $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] = 0;
            $ratio = 0;
            if (strlen($wr) > 0) {
                $ratio = comparetime($val[$i]["time"], $wr);
                $ratio = $ratio[0];
            }
            $rbonus = ($ratio > 0) ? pow($ratio, (2 / $ratio)) : 0;
            $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] = $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] + ($c_val - $i) * (1 + $rbonus);
        }
    }
    foreach ($obj["nub"] as $val) {
        $c_val = count($val);
        for ($i=0; $i<$c_val; $i++) {
            if (!array_key_exists($val[$i]["authid"], $authpts))
                $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] = 0;
            $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] = (array_key_exists("gc", $val[$i])) ? $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] + ($c_val - $i) * pow(0.98, $val[$i]["gc"]) : $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] + ($c_val - $i);
        }
    }
    foreach ($obj["wpn"] as $val) {
        $c_val = count($val);
        for($i=0; $i<$c_val; $i++) {
            if (!array_key_exists($val[$i]["authid"], $authpts))
                $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] = 0;
            $wsw = 1;
            if (array_key_exists("weapon", $val[$i]) && array_key_exists($val[$i]["weapon"], $wpnspeeds))
                $wsw = (250 - $wpnspeeds[$val[$i]["weapon"]]) / (250 - $wpnspeeds["awp"]);
            $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] = (array_key_exists("gc", $val[$i])) ? $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] + ($c_val - $i) * (pow(0.98, $val[$i]["gc"]) + $wsw) : $authpts[$val[$i]["authid"]] + ($c_val - $i) * (1 + $wsw);
        }
    }
    foreach ($authpts as $key => $val) {
        $val = round($val, 2);
        foreach ($obj["pro"] as $k2 => $v2) {
            $c_v2 = count($v2);
            for ($i=0; $i<$c_v2; $i++) { 
                if (trim(strtolower($v2[$i]["authid"])) == trim(strtolower($key)))
                    $res = $v2[$i];
            }
        }
        if(isset($res))
            $points[$res["name"]] = $val;
    }
    uasort($points, function($a, $b) {
        if ($a == $b)
            return 0;
        return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
    });
    return $points;
}
```

Comment: PHP is not a very fast language. Looping over sets with thousands of pieces of data will take a while.

Comment: finally a good question. (-: - let me read it some times to compeletly understand it then I would tell you that is it better to move it to client side use another language or a faster technique to do that.

Comment: If you are getting your data from a database, can you move any of the functionality to happen there?

Comment: Check out HipHop for PHP. But why not use JavaScript on the server side if it works for you? You can get something like PHP or CGI scripts using TeaJS...

Comment: When you're constructing the `$recs` array, can you make it associative so that `$recs[$i][0]` will be the key? Or make a separate associative array that maps keys to indexes in the array. Any time you're searching a large table for unique elements, you should think about turning it into an associative array.

Comment: $recs is retrieved from a .json file which I set a task to create/update daily from a remote .txt file. $obj is retrieved from a database, yes, but to calculate my points correctly I actually need every row in the table.

Comment: @tenub - one question what you meant than javascript? server-side or client-side?

Comment: @Barmar yes I can reconstruct my $recs array. That would probably save some time. However, the bulk of the slowdown is after the first part of finding the $wr value when creating the array to keep track of each user's points and beyond.

Comment: @imsiso I had originally coded it client-side. I don't know much about server-side JS. TeaJS looks interesting though!

Comment: How big is a typical `$val`?

Comment: @tenub - but how, may I know? did you downloaded data in client side and then do that loops and compares in users browser?

Comment: @Barmar `$val` varies 0 to about 40, averaging probably around 12-15 entries. Each of these contain 4 or 5 keys/values (I forget how many columns I'm pulling from my SQL db).

Comment: @imsiso yes, I had originally just used a php script to pull all rows from my sql db and js/ajax to load the massive amount of data in json format. Then I manipulated/calculated from that data all on the client-side via js. I decided to rewrite server-side because what happens if js is disabled in the browser? My page fails..

Comment: ok let me tell you something I think you have tested it in local right? cause in reality the client side would take much time specially if you have a low speed connection.

Comment: everybody how about going on chat?

Comment: Without knowing the back of these and the goal behind the most could be done is what @-barmar said and thing like HipHop would help too.

Comment: @imsiso http://74.91.121.182 is what I'm working on now. Note how unbearably long it takes (95% due to calculating points).

Comment: ok I see its about calculating the points but I should know about structures and way of calculating the points + I may find a way to increase performance and as I mentioned before @-barmar to the most thing.

Comment: @imsiso added entire calcpoints function to original post for you to look at if you want :)

Comment: but now here is about 2.30 AM and my mind is not working very well. And I would work on this later but things may increase the speed is to check and see is there any reason to do all compares in each time and for everyone, or something like this.

Comment: @imsiso alright, will think about how to optimize the function some more. thanks for your interest and help!

Comment: I'm happy if I could helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an associative array containing the data from `$recs` before your loop. In the inner loop, try caching repeated expressions in variables. And use `+=` to avoid evaluating the array expression twice when adding to the elements.

```
$recs_assoc = array();
foreach ($recs as $r) {
    $recs_assoc[$r[0]] = $r[1];
}
$authpts = array();
foreach ($obj["pro"] as $key => $val) {
    $wr = $recs_assoc[$key];
    $c_val = count($val);
    for ($i=0; $i<$c_val; $i++) {
        $thisval = $val[$i];
        $authid = $thisval["authid"];
        if (!array_key_exists($authid, $authpts)) {
            $authpts[$authid] = 0;
        }
        $ratio = 0;
        if (strlen($c_wr) > 0) {
            $ratio = comparetime($thisval["time"], $wr);
            $ratio = $ratio[0];
        }
        $rbonus = ($ratio > 0) ? pow($ratio, (2 / $ratio)) : 0;
        $authpts[$authid] += ($c_val - $i) * (1 + $rbonus);
    }
}
```

You can get rid of the call to `array_key_exists`, if you change the last assignment to:

```
        @$authpts[$authid] += ($c_val - $i) * (1 + $rbonus);
```

The `@` suppresses the warning that would normally result from incrementing a nonexistent element. It will treat the element as if it contained 0, so the correct result is still obtained.

Comment: but I don't think it would increase speed would it?

Comment: I think it should help, although how much is hard to predict. The OP should be able to benchmark it.

Comment: Glad to talk to you love the way you think. (-:

Comment: This definitely helped. In the end after optimizing all of my other code I managed to get the page to process in an average of about 650ms. :)